# TempData moving from view to controler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, tempdata

I am attempting to call a controller via an `actionLink()` in a view.  This controller get's data from a TempData repository.  However, it seems that no matter what I do, if I set the `TempData` repository in the view, it won't go over to the controller?  Should I use `ViewData` instead?  What is your recommendation for a system such as that?

Thanks

Comment: You are not supposed to set TempData from view, if you need that, consider changing your design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TempData, nor ViewData is supposed to be set in a view. A view is supposed to consume data that has been stored in those structures inside your controller actions (well, actually it isn't, a view is supposed to consume a view model but that's another topic).

TempData could be used when you want to persist information between two redirects. It should be set inside a controller action which redirects to another controller action that will read the data:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    SomeModel model = ...
    TempData["foo"] = model;
    return RedirectToAction("Bar");
}

public ActionResult Bar()
{
    var model = TempData["foo"] as SomeModel;
    ...
}
```

So a controller action should get data from the TempData structure only if this action has been invoked after a redirect from another action that set the data. Such controller action should never be invoked from a view because if you have a view this means that this view was rendered from a controller action that presumably set the data into TempData but there is always a risk (if the view performs in between a request to the server - AJAX or something), the TempData will be lost.

For your case, when a view needs to invoke the server there are basically 3 techniques:

- Use an HTML `<form>` with input fields that will send the data to the server
- Use an anchor and pass data as query string parameters to the controller
- Use javascript and send an AJAX request or a redirect to the server

Comment: I was afraid of that.  So how does one handle page refreshes from a button(created from a form) if you have gotten data from a TempData repository?  Currently to refresh via button, I simply call the controller again from an actionLink...  There in lies the problem.  That controller has some info in it from a TempData repository.  If I call that and its null the page won't reload properly.  Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @DmainEvent, that's exactly one of the problems of TempData. Page refreshes with F5. It could be a PITA. Personally I never use TempData. If I need to persist something so that it has to survive page refreshes I persist it in my back-end so that I can always retrieve it if needed given its unique identifier. TempData should really be used for a very short lived object storage mechanism: things like notification messages for example.

Comment: How would you store it in the back-end?  In like a database or is there some mechanism like a session that you use?

Comment: @DmainEvent, when I say back-end this could really mean any centralized storage location allowing this information to be retrieved later. It will depend on the specific requirements of my application. Could range from cookies on the clients, files on the server, going through NoSQL key/value pair storages up to a relational database. Session is out of the question for me. I hate it and never use it.

Comment: I feel your pain.  I despise sessions.  Hmmm: I may need to do a major redesign.

Comment: Here in lies my problem.  I am attempting to get XML between controllers.  I am getting this exception when I attempt to run my site... Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.

Comment: @DmainEvent, maybe you could start a new question, show your exact code, explain your problem, ...

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `TempData` value beforehand, in the controller that renders your view.  The value will then get picked up by the controller action that renders your second (ActionLink) view.