# Tempdata In Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

learning MVC creating a simple date time signup form. i am trying to make two textboxes for the user. One for date and one for time.

I am going to save both values in a single dateTime field in my model.

So i need to figure out how to have a form field stored in tempdata to be accessed in the controller when posted. i can then combine the two text boxes to make a dateTime to store in my model.

I know how to get the tempdata in the controller, its just the razor syntax in the form i cant quite get.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

TempData is not fit for your purpose. You can not assign value in TempData/ViewData in a View. You can assign value in TempData/ViewData in controller only and access those value in View. For more information please refer this question: [TempData moving from view to controler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341802/tempdata-moving-from-view-to-controler)

I suggest you to use a ViewModel in your scenario having all properties what you need in your view. Please look into answer given by Mariusz at [ASP.NET MVC - How exactly to use View Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548376/asp-net-mvc-how-exactly-to-use-view-models)

Answer (score 0):

I think a better practice would be to have a view model containing all the information you want to pass from the form to the controller.

**View Model:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Signup()
{
    var m = new MyViewModel();
    return View(m);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Signup(MyViewModel m)
{
    var username = m.Username;
    var password = m.Password;
    var date = m.Date;
    var time = m.Time;
    // ...
}
```

**View:**

```
@model MvcApplication5.Controllers.MyViewModel

@* ... *@

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Time)

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

}
```